# DataTable equivalent in Jquery to store data?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a form on which I am adding rows dynamically using Jquery.

Please take a look: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/9/)

Now I want to save the data of all rows that has been added in my database using Jquery Ajax call on click event of SAVE button. The point where I am stuck is .. I am not sure how should I extract data of all rows and send it to the webmethod. I mean had it been c# I could have used a DataTable to store data of all rows before sending it to DataBase. I think I should create a string seperated by commas and pipe with data of each row and send it to webmethod. I am not sure if its the right approach and also how this is to be done (ie. creating such a string).

**HTML**

```
<table id="field">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="row1" class="row">
        <td> <span class='num'>1</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><select class="myDropDownLisTId"> <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></select></td><td>
            <input type="submit"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteField">Delete Field</button>
<button type="button" id="btnsave">SAVE</button>
```

Comment: you can use ajax call with the textbox click event..

Comment: I know all that. What I want to know I how can i create a string with values of each row.

Comment: Okay i will give the code please use this and let me know if your problem is solve or not give me few minutes

Comment: Yes sure take your time. Just to make sure I am clear... what I want to know is how to create a concatenated string which has values of each control separated by comma , and row separated by pipe |. 
Because I believe it would be easy to send such a string to webmethod and save the values.

Comment: Check my answer and apply in your code...but i add dynamic textbox and get the value in code behind but you can idea for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 suggestions:

- To keep it as close as what you already have, you could just enclose your table in a form tag, and then you could just submit the form (use something like the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit it via Ajax). The trickiest part will be to bind that data to action parameters. You may be able to receive it in the form of an array, or you could default to looping through properties of the `Request.Form` variable. Make sure you generate proper names for those fields.
- I think the cleanest way to do it would be to have a JavaScript object holding your values, and having the table generated from that object, with 2-way bindings. Something like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) would suit your needs. That way the user enters the data in the table and you'll have it ready to be Json-serialized and sent to the server. Here's a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/GL6nw/) I made.

I wouldn't recommend that approach, but if you wanted to create your own string, you could do something along those lines:

```
$("#btnsave").click(function () {
    var result = "";
    $("#field tr").each(function (iRow, row) {
        $("td input", row).each(function (iField, field) {
            result += $(field).val() + ",";
        });
        result = result + "|";
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

You will have problems if the users types in a comma. That why we use well known serialization formats.

Comment: How about I just create a string.. each control value separated by a comma and each row separated by pipe | 
I think it would be easier to send such a string to the server. But I am not sure how to form such a string by looping over rows.

Comment: You would be reinventing the wheel, but I edited my answer with what you're trying to do. I also added a clean example using KnockoutJS.

Comment: I understand your concern but I am a noob to be honest. 
This code which you just posted seems to be working ok. Can you tell me how to exclude certain input elements with certain class.?

Comment: Sure, you could add an `if (!$(field).is(".my-class"))`

Comment: can you please tell me how can I include dropdown in your code. I mean  `$("td input", row)` gives me all `input` control values but it excludes dropdown `select` controls.

Comment: That's `$("td input, td select", row)`

Answer (score 0):

use ajax call on save button event...
like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reqinfo').click(function () {
       // debugger;
        var emailto = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
        if (emailto != "") {


            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
```

> url: "/EmailService1.svc/EmailService1/emaildata?Email=" + emailto,

```
                // data: dat,
                Accept: 'application/json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                //    debugger;


                },
                error: function (result) {
                   // debugger;

                }
            });
        }
        else {
            //your validation message goes here
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

and add you all data in quesry string and transfer it to webservice..

```
  url: "/EmailService1.svc/EmailService1/emaildata?Email=" + emailto + "data1=" + data1,
```

Comment: I know how to send the data. What I don't know I how to extract data of all rows and form a concatenated string which has values of each control separated by comma , and row separated by pipe |.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _autoComplCounter = 0;
function initialize3(_id) {
    var input_TO = document.getElementById(_id);
    var options2 = { componentRestrictions: { country: 'ID' } };
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_TO, options2);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize3);

function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    var _id = "AutoCompl" + _autoComplCounter;
    _autoComplCounter++;

    return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  type="text" id="' + _id + '" value = "' + value + '" onkeypress = "calcRoute();"  />' +
       '<input type="button" class="superbutton orange" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;

    if (document.getElementById('number').value < 3) {
        document.getElementById('number').value = value;
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        var _id = "AutoCompl" + _autoComplCounter;
        _autoComplCounter++;
        var ht = '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" id="' + _id + '" value = "" onkeypress = "calcRoute();" class="clsgetids" for-action="' + _id + '" />' +
       '<input type="button" class="superbutton orange" value="@Resources.SearchOfferRides.btnRemove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this); calcRoute();" />';
        div.innerHTML = ht;
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var input_TO = document.getElementById(_id);
            var options2 = { componentRestrictions: { country: 'ID' } };
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_TO, options2);
        }, 100);
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
    }
    else {
        alert('Enter only 3 stop point. !!');
    }
}

function RemoveTextBox(div) {
    //calcStopPointRoute();
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;

    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}

function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
    var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
    if (values != null) {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
        }
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
    }
}
  //  window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
</script>
```

And get the value from textbox:

```
  #region stop point
        string[] textboxValues = Request.Form.GetValues("DynamicTextBox");

        if (textboxValues != null)
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < textboxValues.Length; i++)
            {
                if (textboxValues.Length == 1)
                {
                    model.OptionalRoot = textboxValues[0].ToString();
                }
                else if (textboxValues.Length == 2)
                {
                    model.OptionalRoot = textboxValues[0].ToString();
                    model.OptionalRoot2 = textboxValues[1].ToString();
                }
                else if (textboxValues.Length == 3)
                {
                    model.OptionalRoot = textboxValues[0].ToString();
                    model.OptionalRoot2 = textboxValues[1].ToString();
                    model.OptionalRoot3 = textboxValues[2].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    model.OptionalRoot = "";
                    model.OptionalRoot2 = "";
                    model.OptionalRoot3 = "";
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: I just wanted to create a concatenated string of values or each row controls like I mentioned in my comment

Comment: these results you have to give the array of textbox value now can you concat the textbox value string easily..

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
`DataTable` equivalent in javascript is `Array of custom object` (not exact equivalent but we can say that)

or

you roll your own DataTable js class which will have all the functions and properties supported by DataTable class in .NET

**Long answer:**
on client side(aspx)
you define a class `MyClass` and store all your values in array of objects of that class
and then pass that array after `stingyfying` it to web method

```
JSON.stringify(myArray);
```

on the server side(codebehind)
 
you just define the web method to accept a list of objects `List<MyClass>`

**PS:** When calling web method, Asp.net automatically converts json array into `List<Object>` or `Object[]`

**Loooong answer (WHOLE Solution)**

Page aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="App_Themes/SeaBlue/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyClass(title,option,date) {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Option = option;
            this.Date = date;
        }

        function GetJsonData() {
            var myCollection = new Array();

            $(".row").each(function () {
                var curRow = $(this);
                var title = curRow.find(".title").val();
                var option = curRow.find(".myDropDownLisTId").val();
                var date = curRow.find(".datepicker").val();

                var myObj = new MyClass(title, option, date);
                myCollection.push(myObj);
            });

            return JSON.stringify(myCollection);
        }

        function SubmitData() {
            var data = GetJsonData();

            $.ajax({
                url: "testForm.aspx/PostData",
                data: "{ 'myCollection': " + data + " }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            filldd();
            CreateDP();
            var rowstring = "<tr class='row'><td class='number'></td><td><input type='text' class='title'/></td><td><select class='myDropDownLisTId'/><input type='text' class='datepicker'/></td><td><input type='submit'></input></td></tr>";
            $("#addField").click(function (event) {
                $("#field tbody").append(rowstring);
                filldd();
                CreateDP();

                if ($("td").hasClass("number")) {
                    var i = parseInt($(".num:last").text()) + 1;
                    $('.row').last().attr("id", "row" + i);
                    $($("<span class='num'> " + i + " </span>")).appendTo($(".number")).closest("td").removeClass('number');
                }
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $("#deleteField").click(function (event) {
                var lengthRow = $("#field tbody tr").length;
                if (lengthRow > 1)
                    $("#field tbody tr:last").remove();
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            $("#btnsave").click(function () {
                SubmitData();
            });
        });

        function filldd() {
            var data = [
                { id: '0', name: 'test 0' },
                { id: '1', name: 'test 1' },
                { id: '2', name: 'test 2' },
                { id: '3', name: 'test 3' },
                { id: '4', name: 'test 4' },
            ];

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(".myDropDownLisTId").last().append(
                    $('<option />', {
                        'value': data[i].id,
                        'name': data[i].name,
                        'text': data[i].name
                    })
                 );
            }
        }

        function CreateDP() {
            $(".datepicker").last().datepicker();
        }

        $(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function () {
            alert($(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex);
            alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.myDropDownLisTId').val());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
    <table id="field">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="row1" class="row">
                <td>
                    <span class='num'>1</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="myDropDownLisTId">
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="addField">
        Add Field</button>
    <button type="button" id="deleteField">
        Delete Field</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnsave">
        SAVE</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class testForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void PostData(List<MyClass> myCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myCollection.Count);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    string option;

    public string Option
    {
        get { return option; }
        set { option = value; }
    }

    string date;

    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

**References:**
[Json2.js file](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) 
[stringify method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) 
[define a class in js](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)